# The existence of a primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

> Prove that there exists a primitive root $g$ modulo $p$ ($p$ an odd
> prime) such that $g^{p-1}\not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}$

So far, I have been able to prove that if $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ ($p$ an odd prime) and $g^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}$, then $(g+p)^{p-1}\not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}$. I don't know how to continue? Any help I would appreciate.

Comment: If you've proved this, then you need to simply note that if $g$ is ap rimitive rood modulo p, then so is $g+p$.

Comment: What you've proven suffices....where do you see a gap?

Comment: @DS I know, but I don't see why it connects to the problem?

Comment: This has surely been explained on the site earlier. Did you search?

Comment: @AlexNguyen have you proved $(g+p)^{p-1}$ is not $1\pmod p$?

Comment: @DS Yes I already proved

Comment: More clearly, if the primitive root $g$ satisfies the required condition, then we are done. Otherwise, the primitive root $g+p$ satisfies the given conditions. Again, we are done.

Comment: Note $g\equiv g+p\pmod p$ so $(g+p)^k \equiv g^k\pmod p$.  So $g+p$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if and only if $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.  If you have proven what you say you have (and if you've proven any primitive roots exist at all) then I'd say you are done.  $g + p$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ so that $(g+p)^{p-1}\not \equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$.